# Add network packet delay on Windows using command line

Tags: windows, testing, cmd, bandwidth, latency

I am running below command to add and remove packet delay on Linux:

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root netem delay 100ms
tc qdisc del dev eth0 root netem
```

I am looking equivalent Windows command. Any idea?

Comment: Can anybody put 'NetBalancer' tag? I think that may have some command. But not sure about exact command.

Answer (score 0):

I found some useful commands at https://netbalancer.com/docs#command_line__nbcmd_exe_-settings_group_description

```
nbcmd.exe settings priorities default <down priority> <up priority> [down val] [up val] [per connection <true|false>]
```

settings priorities default   [down val] [up val] [per connection ] - set the default priority,  and  are download and respectively upload priority and can accept values Low, Normal, High, Blocked, Ignored, Limited, Delayed, or Dropped. The optional [down val] and [up val] are required only when the selected priority is either Limited, Delayed or Dropped, in these cases the values set the limit in bytes/s, the delay in milliseconds, or the drop rate in float values from 0.0 to 1.0. Option [per connection ] can get only true or false values and sets the "Limit per connection" setting.